# Converted External 3TB WD Mybook Essential to an internal drive, but it's not visible in disk management

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

My external hard-drive (WD MyBook Essential) stopped working a couple months ago (via USB) so I decided to take it apart and try to make it an internal drive.

At first the drive was visible... I formatted and partitioned the drive, assigned it a drive letter then went on to other things. Now my system can't seem to see it at all.

I'm thinking my drive might be dead, but I was hoping someone here might have something else to say.

**Background information**

*-Drive was visible, but it was definitely sluggish when I renamed the drive 
(i.e. the only information written to the drive while running)*

*-Hard drive is spinning and SATA cable is connected*

Edit: Thanks for the help. As I figured, the drive is almost dead. 
Took a couple days for it to appear, but the SMART data & warnings don't lie

Comment: Not a lot of info to go on, but it sounds like the drive is dead/dying.  Checking the SMART data might give some hints, but will likely just verify the behavior you've been seeing.

Comment: MBR or GPT? If you hook it back into the external enclosure, does it work? Can you post a screen shot of the Disk Management window?

Comment: See hdd at BIOS all size? Not? - Upgrade BIOS.